# How to display posts on certain pages and exclude them from the homepage?

Tags: wordpress

I have all my posts set up in certain categories.

I would like to display my posts on certain pages depending on the category and hide them on the homepage. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty basic Wordpress stuff: [Category Templates « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates) and Dashboard>>Settings>>Reading and [Custom Post Limits | coffee2code.com](http://coffee2code.com/wp-plugins/custom-post-limits/)